# Write a query to get output as shown below

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

A table name ***player*** having some columns & data in the table are as follows:

```
**PID**|**PNAME**|**CITY**|**TEAM**|**SALARY**|**NO_OF_PENALTIES**

  1001   ozil     istanbul  germany  500000      1

  1002   messi     madrid   arsenal  500000      2

  1003  ronaldo    manc      uk      600000      1

  1004  puyol      sussex   germany  400000      3

  1005  fabregas   manchester uk     450000      2

  1006  costa      ankara   turkey   400000      3

  1007  beckham    london   uk       600000      2
```

This is the table.Write a query I want record if team name is "germany" & no_of_penalties=1 then I want to get the record.If team name is "uk" & no_of_penalties=2 then I don't want to get the record.
Mean according to the above records as per the query I want to get the record having pid=1001 & pid=1003.
But when I write the query as shown below:

```
select * from player where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) or not (team='uk' and no_of_penalties=2) and team in ('germany','uk');
```

Then after execute above query the output looks like having pid=1001, 1003, 1004 as shown below

```
**PID**|**PNAME**|**CITY**|**TEAM**|**SALARY**|**NO_OF_PENALTIES**

1001    ozil     istanbul   germany  500000        1

1003    ronaldo  manc       uk       600000        1

1004    puyol   sussex      germany  400000        3
```

So could you please solve me the problem?

Comment: Answer is correct as per your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
select * from player 
  where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) 
  or (team='uk' and no_of_penalties!=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are mutually exclusive data, so it should be with AND (not OR). Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM player
WHERE (
        team = 'germany'
        AND no_of_penalties = 1
        )
    AND NOT (
        team = 'uk'
        AND no_of_penalties = 2
        )
    AND team IN (
        'germany'
        ,'uk'
        ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * From Player Where 
(Team = 'Germany' AND No_Of_Penalties = 1) 
AND NOT
(Team = "UK" AND No_Of_Penalties = 2)

Forgive me if I am wrong as I find your question hard to understand clearly but you put "If team name is "uk" & no_of_penalties=2 then I don't want to get the record" meaning you dont want the value of 2 however the answer you selected will show those with value of 2

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
    select * from player 
  where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) 
union all
select * from player 
  where  (team='uk' and no_of_penalties!=2)
```